# How to change the name of <iostream> library in c++?

Tags: c++, iostream

I want to change just the name & keep the functioning of the library as it is .
Is that possible in c++ language?

Comment: Why would you do that?

Comment: I am  thought about it & I want to see if it is possible, isn't it?

Comment: The files are on your computer, you can rename the file to whatever you want. Just... don't. If it's a matter of laziness that you don't wish to type "iostream", or perhaps you often find yourself including 2-3 files, you could take a look at forced includes or precompiled headers. But without any other context to a _problem_ (if any) it's hard to answer

Answer (score 6):

Sure...

You can write your own header called `foo` with the contents

```
#include <iostream>
```

and place it at `/usr/include/foo` or whatever location your compiler searches for headers. Then you can do

```
#include <foo>
```

Why you would want to do this, I have no idea.

Comment: But that wouldn't work like the actual <iostream> library right?

Comment: @A.K. What do you mean? Including the new header will be exactly as if you included `iostream` itself.